# $g(t)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-t^2}$ Find an expression for $g^{n}(t)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> In this question, $g^2(x)$ denotes $g(g(x))$, $g^3(x)$ denotes $g(g(g(x)))$ and so on.
>
> Q: The function $g(t)$ is defined, for $|t| \leq 1$ by
> $g(t)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-t^2}$. Find an expression
> for $g^{n}(t)$ for any positive integer $n$. *Hint: Let
> $t=\sin(\theta)$*

I am creating this thread because I don't know how to handle the absolute value which arises from this problem. I choose to consider the positive value of the absolute value and it happened to be the correct solution my textbook was after. But I don't fully understand the problem.

$g(\sin{\theta}) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{\theta} + \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin{\theta}+\frac{1}{2}|\cos{\theta}|$

Now in the following line, I choose to take the positive value of cosine and for subsequent compositions, I keep taking the positive value. But I realize this composition is not the only possible result. We could take $+-+-+-$ and this would result in a composition that is periodic?

$g(\sin{\theta}) = \sin({\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}})$

$g^2(\sin{\theta}) = \sin({\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}})$

$g^3(\sin{\theta}) = \sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}{2})$

$$\therefore g^n(\sin{\theta}) = \sin(\theta+\frac{n\pi}{6}) = \sin(\sin^{-1}(t)+\frac{n\pi}{6}) $$

This can then be proven with induction. But I won't bore you with that. I am more interested in how to handle the different cases that arise according to what value you choose for $|\cos({\theta+\frac{\pi n}{6}})|$ in further compositions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If $\alpha \in [-\pi/2;\pi/2]$ then $g(\sin\alpha)=\sin(\alpha+\pi/6)$.
2. If $\alpha \in [\pi/2;3\pi/2]$ then $g(\sin\alpha)=\sin(\alpha-\pi/6)$.

Let $\theta=\arcsin t \in [-\pi/2;\pi/2]$.
Let $n_1=1+\lfloor \frac{\pi/2-\theta}{\pi/6}\rfloor$.

$-\pi/2\leq \theta+\frac{\pi}{6}(n-1) \leq \pi/2$ for $1\leq n \leq n_1$, then $g^{n}(\sin\theta)=\sin(\theta+n\pi/6)$ for $1\leq n \leq n_1$.

$\theta+\frac{\pi}{6}n_1 > \pi/2$, then $g^{n_1+1}(\sin\theta)=g(g^{n_1}(\sin\theta))=g(\sin(\theta+n_1 \pi/6))=\sin(\theta+(n_1-1) \pi/6)=g^{n_1-1}(\sin\theta)$.

So for $n > n_1$: $g^n(\sin\theta)=\sin(\theta+(n_1-r)\pi/6)$, where $r=mod(n-n_1,2)=\frac{1-(-1)^{n-n_1}}{2}$.

Both answers can be combined in one formula

$$g^{n}(t)=\sin(\arcsin t+(n-u)\pi/6),$$

where $u=v+\frac{1-(-1)^v}{2}$, $v=\frac{n-n_1+|n-n_1|}{2}$, $n_1=1+\lfloor \frac{\pi/2-\arcsin t}{\pi/6}\rfloor$.

Comment: Currently trying to make sense of this $n_1$ term that you've defined

Comment: $n_1$ is minimum positive integer such that $\arcsin t + n_1 \pi /6 > \pi /2$

Comment: $n_1=1+\lfloor \frac{\pi/2-\theta}{\pi/6} \rfloor$ can be rewritten as $n_1 = 4 - \lceil \frac{6 \theta}{\pi} \rceil$